# how to show a specific container on button click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a container with all it's content based on which button a user clicks. I have the following code , but it's not working ? I have placed the jquery in script tags on the html page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data1').click(function() {
    $('.all_info').show();
    $('.charts1').hide();
  });
  
  $('#data2').click(function() {
    $('.charts1').show();
    $('.all_info').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.all_info {
  display: none;
}

.charts1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <center>Results</center>
</h1>
<div class="data_btns_container">
  <div class="data_btns_group">
    <button type="button" class="data_btns_inside" id="data1">Data1</button>
    <button type="button" class="data_btns_inside" id="data2">Data2</button>
    <button type="button" class="data_btns_inside" id="data3">Data2</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid all_info">
  <p>Test123</p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid charts1">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the code you added to the question and put it in to an executable snippet where it works correctly. Please check the console for errors in your local version, and ensure you've added the necessary libraries, such as jQuery.js, to the page correctly.

Comment: I ran your code and everything is working. But note that `charts1` class does not have any content!

Comment: I also tested your code, it works. Your canvas is empty, maybe it's confusing you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for but I wrote something completely different but has similar outcome just to give you an idea of what I think you want and how you can achieve it. Have a look at it and let me know.

```js
//When a button is clicked
$('button').on('click',function(){
  //we get the name of the div that matches the data attribute of the button
  var div = $(this).data('name');
  //if that div is visible, we hide it
  if($('.'+div).hasClass('view-div')){
    $('.default').removeClass('view-div');  
  }else{
    //if the div was not visible we hide any div that might be and show this one
    $('.default').removeClass('view-div');
    $('.'+div).addClass('view-div');
  }
});
```

```css
.default {
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.view-div {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div>
  <button data-name="div-1">Button 1</button>
  <button data-name="div-2">Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="div-1 default">
  <h4>Div 1 Content</h4>
  <span>Some More!</span>
</div>
<div class="div-2 default">
  <h4>Div 2 Content</h4>
  <span>More Content</span>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned I'm using Django and have a 'main.js' file inside of my project that changes elements in the 'all_info' container, so rather than placing the jquery code in a script tag within my html page, I had to be place it in the 'main.js' for it to work. Thanks for the help anyways.